# How can I add a model to a custom module?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, model

I'm extending custom module. One of the functions using dynamic models load, based on input param

```
$reportProcessor = Mage::getSingleton(
    'amreports_reports/' . $data['report_type']
);
```

If I creating my new `$data['report_type']`, I need to add a new model. How can I do this for existing module?

Answer (score 0):

**In /app/etc/modules/Your_Module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**In /app/code/local/Your/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
        <modules>
                <Your_Module>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                </Your_Module>
        </modules>
        <global>
                <models>
                    <your_module>
                       <class>Your_Module_Model</class>
                    </your_module>
                </models>
        </global>
</config>
```

**In /app/code/local/Your/Module/Model/Extend.php**

```
<?php
class Your_Module_Model_Extend extends Custom_Module_Model_Someclass {
    public function fromCustomModule() {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

The terms `Your`, `Module`, and `Extend` are arbitrary, and you can change them, but `Custom_Module_Model_Someclass` must be the existing model of the custom extension that you are trying to modify.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunatelly it's not what I'm looking for. I need to "implement" model to custom module. I'll try to explain. In my case, I'm calling model in custom module, which isn't exists and I want to add this model in my module without rewriting function, which call this "virtual" model.

Answer (score 0):

I  had some task as in question.

I'm working with Magento 1.9.2

I tried direct define new model in my module that not exists in "base" custom module. And it worked.

For question it will similar

`config.xml`

```
 <amreports_reports>
    <rewrite>
       <my_model_name>My_Model_Class</my_model_name>
    </rewrite>
 <amreports_reports>
```

And now is possible use

```
$reportProcessor = Mage::getSingleton('amreports_reports/my_model_name')
```